# Nginx infinite redirect loop when using multiple proxy_pass

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need some help with this one, because I've been stuck on it for far too long. Here's my **use case**:

I need to proxy from my main domain `test.co` to two separate locations, at various endpoints. For now, however, I simply want to use location blocks for `= /` (homepage) and `/` (everywhere else). The two separate locations are `webflow.test.co` at the homepage (real domain removed for anonymity), a subdomain of ours, and our NodeJS server at everywhere else. Here's **the problem:**

Using the code below, (my nginx.conf, ran through an ElasticBeanstalk instance) results in an infinite redirect loop at the homepage `/`. The error in the browser is ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, but it's clear what's happening: the browser is redirecting from the original `test.co` to `https://test.co`, to `https://test.co` again ad nasueum. I've tried changing nearly everything I could think of... some examples: the server_name was originally a regex, I removed that. The `/` location block was once a regex, had some issues with that, I removed it. Added `X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme` to the headers.

Those are just a few things, but here's the bottom line: the only thing that seems to work, through 3 days of testing, is removing `proxy_set_header Host $host;`, or setting it to `webflow.test.co` (thus defeating the purpose). This is an unacceptable solution, of course, because I need the URL to match my original domain... but it **does** solve the problem. Perhaps that can give you guys some insight.

Here's my code:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

# Redirect all non-HTTPS to non-WWW HTTPS
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name "~^(?:www\.)?(.*)$";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect WWW HTTP to non-WWW HTTP
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
}

# Reverse-proxy to http://nodejs
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name test.co;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://webflow.test.co;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Thanks so much to anyone who takes the time to solve this one. It's been a thorn in my side, and I've gotta move on to something fresh. Will accept the first answer that works immediately.

Some other notes - **may be important** - that I'll add to if things get uncovered:

- curl -v `test.co` returns a 301 with a Location of https://test.co.
- curl -v `https://test.co` returns the same - 301 with a Location of
  https://test.co
- Removing the two non-WWW and non-HTTPS at the top doesn't solve the
  problem. It makes `test.co` unreachable, but `https://test.co` still
  redirect loops

Comment: what and where is `proxy_pass http://webflow.test.co;` ?

Comment: it's a proxy to an external webpage (hosted with webflow), which we're serving instead of the one located on our node server.

Comment: Why am I not seeing the ssl config in this? You are trying to reach https but the config has no SSL?

Comment: A little more info: SSL is configured via the ElasticBeanstalk console, through the Load Balancer. I'm going to assume they set things up on their end. Interesting fact about our setup though: we're forwarding 80 to 8080 and 443 to 4430, the port shown used above, and forwarding SSL traffic through there. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you change the two location blocks to just return a code ? return 444 and return 555. And tell me if you get any of the codes instead of loop?

Comment: I changed the first location block `= /` - the one where I see the redirect loop - to return 418 (it didn't like me inputting 444 or 555). It returned it successfully. `location = / {
  return 418;
 }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153808/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-ryan-spicer).

Comment: Note to all: This issue is still not solved, and I can't for the life of me figure it out. If anybody has any insights, please take some time to look in to this. I'll likely be moving on to another solution, but it won't be an ideal one - this is our best bet, by far.